# Why is my program entering a loop (and staying there) when condition is false (Ada)?

Tags: while-loop, ada

There is a variable in my program that controls whether or not the user would like to repeat the program called "done." if done = '0', the program repeats; if done = '1', the program exits. If the user enters a value that is anything other than '0' or '1', it enters a loop that prompts them to enter something valid until they do. The problem is that it enters this loop (infinitely) regardless of what the user enters.

The code I am concerned with starts on line 63; here is the full .adb file:

```
with ada.text_io; use ada.text_io;
with ada.strings.bounded;
with unchecked_conversion;
with stack;

procedure main is
   package int_io is new ada.text_io.integer_io(integer);

   stack_type : positive;
   stack_size : natural;
begin
   loop
      -- Select stack type
      put_line("Select stack type by inputting corresponding number: ");
      put_line("1) Character");
      put_line("2) Integer");
      put_line("3) Date");
      int_io.get(stack_type);

      -- Select size of stack
      put_line("Enter the maximum size of your stack: ");
      int_io.get(stack_size);

      case (stack_type) is
     -- Character stack (option C/D)
     when 1 =>
        declare
           package char_stack is new stack(stack_size, character); use char_stack;
           char : character;
           done : integer := 0;
           num_chars : natural := 48;  -- 48 = ASCII '0'
           -- Reflects how many characters (including the number) of the name on top of the stack; used for limit in popping for loop
           num_to_pop : natural := 0;

           -- Pop and print characters from stack
           procedure print_chars is
           begin
          for i in 0 .. (num_to_pop - 1) loop
             put(char_stack.pop);
          end loop;

          -- Reset num_to_pop
          num_to_pop := 0;
           end print_chars;
        begin
           put_line("Enter characters; To finish sequence, terminate with '#': ");
           new_line;

           while (done /= 1) loop
          while (char /= '#') loop
             get(char);
             if (char /= '#') then
            push(char);
            num_chars := num_chars + 1;
             end if;
          end loop;

          -- Push number of characters onto stack; reset num_to_pop; reset num_chars
          push(character'val(num_chars));
          num_to_pop := (character'pos(peek)) - 47;
          num_chars := 48;

          -- Ask user if they wish to continue
          new_line;
          put_line("To repeat, enter '0'; to terminate program, enter '1': ");
          new_line;
          int_io.get(done);

          -------------TEST----------------
          new_line;
          int_io.put(done);
          new_line;
          ---------------------------------
          while (done /= 0 or done /= 1) loop
             put_line("Please enter either a '0' or a '1'.");
             new_line;
             int_io.get(done);
          end loop;
           end loop;
     end;
    -- Integer stack (option B)
    when 2 =>
        begin
           put("asfsF");
        --
     end;
     -- Date stack (option A)
     when 3 =>
        begin
           put("Asfasdf");
        --
        end;

     when others =>
        begin
           put("asdfasdF");
        end;
    end case;
   end loop;
end main;
```

Comment: Since you’re only concerned with the code around line 63, it would have made life easier for us if you had reduced your code to just the relevant bits (after all, without package `Stack`, we can’t compile it anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write

```
      while (done /= 0 or done /= 1) loop
```

but you should have written

```
      while (done /= 0 and done /= 1) loop
```

or even, since Ada doesn’t need the parentheses here,

```
      while done /= 0 and done /= 1 loop
```

or, applying De Morgan’s law,

```
      while not (done = 0 or done = 1) loop
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. That makes sense to me now that I think about it. Even if it is either 1 or 0, it can't be both, so one of those conditions is always going to be satisfied. I get it now.